# Why does the constness of a reference affect whether it can be initialized with a variable of a different type?

Tags: c++, reference, language-design

Why does this code fail to compile?

```
 double d ;
 int & i1 = d // Compilation FAILS
```

While this one does?

```
 double d ;
 const int & i = d // Compilation Succeeds
```

Please, I am interested in knowing what was in mind of C++ designers that they allowed one behavior while disallowed another.

I know in either case it's immoral, independent of technically possible or not. 
Also FYI I am using GCC on mac with "-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0"

Comment: Neither should compile, what compiler are you trying it on?

Comment: On which compiler does that succeed? There's no conversion from `double*` to `int&`.

Comment: Both GCC and MSVC reject that.

Comment: Are you sure that the first version compiles? It doesn't with g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Comment: @cat plus plus : please try this code

 double d = 100;
 const int & i = d;

Comment: @Ajeet That's not the code you posted.

Comment: @cat plus plus Fixed a typo...

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes  Fixed a major typo. sorry about that...

Comment: @Ajeet : Perhaps in the future you'll make sure your question is sensical _before_ posting it. ;-]

Comment: gcc 2.96 accepts both variants. gcc 4.1.2 only allows the second. (It works by creating a temporary const int, which the reference is then bound to. The temporary lasts until the variable goes out of scope.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it creates a temporary `int` where the double is converted, and mutable references cannot bind to temporaries, whereas `const` ones can.

The problem with allowing mutable references to bind to temporaries is relatively clear.

```
Derived* ptr;
Base*& baseptr = ptr;
baseptr = new Base;
ptr->SomeDerivedFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say

```
double d = 5.0; 
double &dd = d;
```

then `dd` changes as `d` changes.  But, if you were to say,

```
const double &dd = d;
```

`dd` is a *const* double reference – its value cannot change, even if `d` changes, making the “reference” part of its definition impossible. Hence when you use `const`, the `&` causes a temporary to be created, and sets the reference to refer to that temporary.  `const int & i = d;` therefore is effectively the same as `const int i = d;`   which is allowed.

Comment: That's not true at all- a reference is a reference, `const` or not.